# Is there another method of handling Time Travel in Data Science in cases where the underlying system does not have that feature?

Tags: data-science, database-schema

I'm looking for a term or technique that might store schema changes over time.  What did we do before Big Data?  Is there something like a "Schema Ledger" that can capture things like "*this field was renamed to that field?*" Or "*this SKU was moved to a different department on July 4th, 1976?*"